# Average Regret Bounds for Linear Stochastic Bandits

Tags: pr.probability, lg.learning, online-learning

I am reading this paper on linear stochastic bandits :

http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4417-improved-algorithms-for-linear-stochastic-bandits.pdf

All the results are stated in a high-probability setting, that is $\delta$ is a parameter to the algorithm , the regret at time $T$ is such that ,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(R_T > f(T) ) \geq 1 - \delta
\end{align*}

Is there any resource where the bounds are obtained in the form $\mathbb{E}[R_T] \leq f(T) $ ?

Trivially replacing $\delta = \frac{1}{T}$, does not give an anytime algorithm, that is the bounds don't hold for all $t > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "[doubling trick](https://books.google.com/books?id=i8hQhp1a62UC&pg=766)," you can turn your favorite high probability algorithm (e.g. [LinUCB](http://www.research.rutgers.edu/~lihong/pub/Li10Contextual.pdf)) to be an anytime algorithm with expected regret as a function of $T$, usually giving a $\tilde{O}(\sqrt{T})$ dependence without knowing $T$ in advance.

This turns out to be tight, i.e. in [Chu et al. (2011)](http://www.levreyzin.com/papers/ChuLRS11.pdf), we give lower bounds on expected regret of $\Theta(\sqrt{dT})$ for the $d$-dimensional linear stochastic bandit problem.  Hence, the expected regret, in the worst case, will indeed still be a function of $T$.

Comment: Hi Lev, Thanks for the answer. I am still trying to understand this, as i am new to this field.

Comment: I had one more question. If the set of arms are finite (say $K$) does the regret scale something like $ O(d \log ^2 t)$ where $d$ is the dimension of the feature vectors ?

Comment: These models have many intricate details.  In many versions of the linear bandit problem, the number of arms is hidden in $d$, since the feature vector can encode "arm features" for each arm.  Regarding the dependence on $T$, most bandit problems have two types of bounds in the stochastic case, a "problem dependent bound" that scales polylog($T$) and a minimax bound that scales approximately as $\sqrt{T}$.  For the adversarial version of the problem, the bounds usually scale approximately as $\sqrt{T}$. This can even be seen in the basic bandit problem when comparing EXP3 vs UCB regret bounds.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I understand it. Whenever there is a gap $\Delta$ between the optimal choice and the sub-optimal ones you can achieve problem dependent bounds which are polylog.

Comment: You can always achieve the problem-dependent bounds, but the gap appears in them.  When the gap is "worst-case," i.e. a particular function of $T$, then those bounds also degrade to $\approx T^{1/2}$.